# how to create a class to initialize culture for localization

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

i am trying to localize my asp.net pages. so far i have only been localize my master page.

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["CultureInfo"];

    if (cookie != null && cookie.Value != null)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-CA");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-CA");
    }
}
```

MasterPage.master.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //only does it on non-postback because otherwise 
    //the selected value will not reach event handler correctly
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlLanguage.SelectedValue = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
    }
}

protected void ddlLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Sets the cookie that is to be used by Global.asax
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CultureInfo");
    cookie.Value = ddlLanguage.SelectedValue;
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

    //Set the culture and reload for immediate effect.
    //Future effects are handled by Global.asax
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(ddlLanguage.SelectedValue);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(ddlLanguage.SelectedValue);
    Server.Transfer(Request.Path);
}
```

MasterPage.master

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLanguage" runat="server"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLanguage_SelectedIndexChanged"
        AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, users_English %>" Value="en-CA" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, users_French %>" Value="fr-CA" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

How can i create a common class for all my other web pages to inherit from the common class.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that inherits from System.Web.Ui.Page (i.e. public class CommonPage: System.Web.Ui.Page) add/override methods you want and all your pages can inherit from this newly created one.